# Terraform N accounts Provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws, okta

I have the following setup. I am using Okta with AWS Organizations and Terraform. I want to include the identity provider that is used for AWS Client VPN in all of the accounts through the terraform code. I was thinking that I could just create a list of providers with dynamic configuration for assuming a specific role, however it seems like it doesnt work. Creation of the separate providers is out of the scope, cause the number of accounts that is used is in hundreds.

Main points:

1. List of accounts is in hundreds - creation of the provider normal way without any loop is out of the scope
2. I want to be able to create all the specific resources to **ALL of those accounts** (currently I have a separate module that I am provisioning all of the resources)

Example code:

```
provider "aws" {
    alias   = "all_accounts"
    access_key = var.aws_access_key
    secret_key = var.aws_secret_key
# THIS DYNAMIC SEEMS LIKE ITS NOT WORKING
#   dynamic "assume_role" {
#       for_each = local.MAP_OF_ACCOUNT_IDS_AND_ROLES
#       content {
#           role_arn = each.value
#       }
#   }
    region = "eu-central-1"
}

module "my_module" {
    source = "./modules/my_module"
    count         = length(local.MAP_OF_ACCOUNT_IDS_AND_ROLES)
    providers      = {
        aws = aws.all_accounts[count.index]
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea how to do it in the terraform?

Comment: The code you tried doesn't even make sense. Your code wasn't attempting to create multiple providers, it was attempting to have a single provider assume multiple roles all at once. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Do you want to run this terraform code once and have it create resources in hundreds of AWS accounts all at the same time? Or are you simply trying to make the single AWS account it will deploy resources to configurable?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to run this terraform code once and have it create resources in hundreds of AWS accounts all at the same time

Comment: You will have to create hundreds of `provider` blocks then. It may be "out of scope" but that doesn't change the fact that Terraform does not support dynamic creation of providers. You might think about having the Terraform code work with a single account, and wrapping the Terraform code in a script that calls it once for each account.

Comment: And it is not possible to generate those providers through any for_each/count method right?

Comment: The words "Terraform does not support dynamic creation of providers" literally means you cannot use `for_each` or `count` to create providers.

Comment: Thanks, well it seems it has to be solved differently then

Comment: @HubertBratek what CI/CD tool you want to use to perform this?

Comment: I was hoping to do it with combinations of GitHub Actions & TF Cloud

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to check if [AWS AFT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/userguide/aft-overview.html) would fit your use case.

AWS AFT will help you creating/customizing the AWS accounts in your organisation with a consistent approach.

For your use case you could leverage the global account customisation to deploy this Identity provider in all accounts.

Yet, the hole product might be a overhead if you don't have any other use case.